# How do I implement minimum 5 characters validation in this ant design login form ? I cant find the examples

Tags: reactjs, antd

I looked at all the examples of ant.design form but cant find the validation for minimum length for the textboxes. can u please help?

https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#header

https://codesandbox.io/s/pww70x7y6q

```
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              placeholder="Username"
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
            initialValue: true,
          })(<Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>)}
          <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">
            Forgot password
          </a>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a href="">register now!</a>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(NormalLoginForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, mountNode);
```

How do I implement minimum 5 characters validation in this ant design login form ? I cant find the examples.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-satoshi-tvs6o

Comment: The docs for the textbox are here: https://ant.design/components/input/

Answer (score 26):

You can add more rules for your input:

```
<Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator('username', {
        rules: [
            { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' },
            { min: 5, message: 'Username must be minimum 5 characters.' },
        ],
      })(
        <Input
          prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
          placeholder="Username"
        />,
      )}
    </Form.Item>
```

For other validation rules visit [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#Validation-Rules).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can check it here -

```
validator: async (rule, value) => {
throw new Error('Something wrong!');
}

// or

validator(rule, value, callback) => {
try {
throw new Error('Something wrong!');
} catch (err) {
callback(err);
}
}
```

For more details - https://ant.design/components/form/#FAQ

My version -

```
<Form.Item
                label="test"
                name="test"
                className={"text-left"}
                rules={[{required: true, message: 'Please input 
test!'},
                    ({getFieldValue}) => ({
                        validator(_, value) {
                            if (getFieldValue('test').length < 3) {
                                return Promise.reject('Custom error 
message!');
                            }
                            return Promise.resolve();
                        },
                    }),
                ]}
            >
                <Input id="test" maxLength={80}/>
            </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

what i understand from your question. you need to limit the input length in the textboxes

As you have added rules like this

```
 rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
```

You need to add more rules like this

```
rules: [
   { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' },
   {validator: this.anyValidation}
 ],

 anyValidation = (rule, value, callback) => {
 const { form } = this.props;
 if (value.length > 5) {
  callback('Input exceed five characters limit');
 } else {
  callback();
 }
 };
```

Comment: where did you find that you could add a custom validation with "validator"? how do you know that anyValidation has these 3 parameters? I'm asking this because I did not see any example like this in the antd v4 docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to akash ingole's answer I was able to setup custom validation using the following setup:

```
        <Form.Item
            name="name"
            rules={[
              { required: true, message: 'Please input the name of your new store' },
              ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
                validator() {
                  if (hasNumber(getFieldValue('name'))) {
                    return Promise.reject(new Error("Names cannot contain numbers"))
                  }
                  return Promise.resolve();
                }
              }),
            ]}
          >
            <Input size="large" placeholder="Name" />
        </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score -1):

By giving max length for the input you can limit the characters in the input field.

Comment: You may have read the original question wrong, he is looking to implement a requirement for a minimum of 5 characters, not a maximum